# Unable to install Tensorflow on Anaconda Environment

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

This is the error I get when I try to install TensorFlow on Anaconda environment

I am using python 3.11.5 with this env.

```
(ai-env) C:\Users\ahmet>conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package tensorflow-1.7.0-0 requires tensorflow-base 1.7.0, but none of the providers can be installed

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ pin-1 is installable and it requires
│  └─ python 3.11.* , which can be installed;
└─ tensorflow is not installable because there are no viable options
   ├─ tensorflow [0.12.1|1.0.0|...|1.9.0] would require
   │  └─ python [3.5* |3.5.* |>=3.5,<3.6.0a0 ], which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ tensorflow [1.10.0|1.13.1|...|1.9.0] would require
   │  ├─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │  └─ tensorflow-base [1.13.1 py36_4|1.13.1 py36_5|...|1.14.0 py36h9f0ad1d_0], which requires
   │     └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ tensorflow [1.13.1|1.14.0|...|2.9.1] would require
   │  ├─ python [3.7.* |>=3.7,<3.8.0a0 ], which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │  └─ tensorflow-base [1.13.1 py37_7|1.14.0 py37hc8dfbb8_0], which requires
   │     └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ tensorflow [1.10.0|1.11.0|...|2.1.0] would require
   │  └─ python [3.6* |3.6.* ], which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ tensorflow [1.7.0|1.7.1|1.8.0] would require
   │  └─ tensorflow-base [1.7.0 |1.7.1 |1.8.0 ] but there are no viable options
   │     ├─ tensorflow-base [1.7.0|1.7.1|1.8.0] would require
   │     │  └─ python >=3.5,<3.6.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │     └─ tensorflow-base [1.13.1|1.13.2|...|1.8.0], which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
   ├─ tensorflow [2.10.0|2.8.2|2.9.1] would require
   │  └─ python 3.10.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ tensorflow [2.10.0|2.3.0|...|2.9.1] would require
   │  └─ python 3.8.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   └─ tensorflow [2.10.0|2.5.0|2.6.0|2.8.2|2.9.1] would require
      └─ python 3.9.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.11.* (labeled as 'pin-1')
```

- Search the net for this specific error but find nothing similar.
- Uninstalled anaconda and start with a fresh instance.

  Still same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1: Unpin Python version (if you have it pinned)

conda config --remove pinned_packages python=3.11

## Step 2: Create a new environment with a compatible Python version

## For instance, TensorFlow 2.x works well with Python 3.8 or 3.9

conda create -n tf_env python=3.8

## Step 3: Activate the new environment

conda activate tf_env

## Step 4: Install TensorFlow

conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

Comment: Now I am getting this error and I have no information about "pinning"

(ai-env) C:\Users\ahmet>conda config --remove pinned_packages python=3.11

CondaKeyError: 'pinned_packages': key 'pinned_packages' is not in the config file

Comment: The error message CondaKeyError: 'pinned_packages': key 'pinned_packages' is not in the config file indicates that the pinned_packages key, which you are trying to remove, does not exist in the Conda configuration file. This typically means that Python 3.11 is not actually pinned in your Conda environment, or it might be pinned in a different way than expected.  # Create a new environment with a compatible Python version
conda create -n tf_env python=3.8

# Activate the new environment
conda activate tf_env

# Install TensorFlow
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

Comment: I have tried with 3.8 and it installed on a maiden env. But.. Can't I install it with 3.11 or above and most importantly on an existing env (with python 3.11.5)

Comment: If you want to attempt the installation in your existing Python 3.11 environment, you can use pip, which sometimes has more up-to-date packages than Conda. However, be aware that this might not work if TensorFlow hasn't been updated for Python 3.11 compatibility. # Activate your existing environment
conda activate your_env_name

# Attempt to install TensorFlow using pip
pip install tensorflow

Comment: I have checked from tensorflow website "https://www.tensorflow.org/install?hl=en". With pip I was able to install tensorflow on a fresh evn with python 3.11.5

Answer (score 0):

Later on I found more information.

In the error conda tells me that it is using a libmamba solver.

With this information provided here:
[Conda:conda-libmamba-solver](https://conda.github.io/conda-libmamba-solver/user-guide/)

I have found the `.condarc` file under my user folder and change the solver to `classic` again.

I didn't configured my conda to use libmamba solver. I have no idea how it got there.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
```

You can paste this in "anaconda's cmd.exe prompt".

After installing, for activation:

```
conda activate tf
```

and paste this, that's it. [More details here](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/working-with-conda/applications/tensorflow/).